# why this.setState going to "is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, setstate

Im trying build simple app to learn how to make api calls. 
When I'm trying to `setState` in react with `onClick` function I'v created, every time I'v tried to invoke I get

> not a function

I tried to bind this like this:

```
this.setState(() => ({
  rowPos: null
}).bind(this))
```

but that did not worked also, I get the error:

> (intermediate value).bind is not a function

there is constructor with state object:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    endpoint: 'https://jolapatola5.fakturownia.pl/invoices.json',
    params: {
      api_token: 'B5Lg3uPBCMcDNX5lsQOM/jolapatola5',
      invoice: {
        "kind": "vat",
        "number": null,
        "sell_date": "2019-07-14",
        "place": 'Lublin',
        "sell_date": "2019-07-14",
        "issue_date": "2019-07-14",
        "payment_to": "2019-07-21",
        "buyer_name": "aaa",
        "buyer_tax_no": "5252445767",
        "buyer_street": "aaa",
        "buyer_post_code": "",
        "buyer_city": "",
        "seller_name": 'aaa',
        "seller_street": '',
        "seller_post_code": '',
        "seller_city": '',
        "seller_bank_account": '',
        "seller_tax_no": '',
        positions: [{
            "name": "Produkt A1",
            "tax": 23,
            "total_price_gross": 10.23,
            "quantity": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "Produkt A1",
            "tax": 23,
            "total_price_gross": 10.23,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  this.removeProductRow = this.removeProductRow.bind(this);
}
```

and method I'm trying to invoke `onClick`:

```js
removeProductRow(id) {
  let rowPos = this.state.params.invoice.positions[id];

  this.setState(() => ({
    rowPos: null
  }).bind(this))

  console.log(rowPos)
};
```

id is passed when I'm mapping components

The result I'm trying to perform is set the `this.state.params.invoice.position` alias `rowPos` to `null`, now its an `object`.

Thanks for any help

EDIT: there is the way I'm mapping components:

```js
{
  this.state.params.invoice.positions.map(function(item,index){
  return 
    <ItemRow key={index} removeProductRow={() => this.removeProductRow(index)}/>
  },this)
}
```

Comment: you don't need to bind setState. simply do  this.setState({
            rowPos: null
        })

Comment: Actually the bind goes to the "}" end of scope. Sou yours would be this.setState(() => ({
            rowPos: null
        }.bind(this)))

Comment: @Marco , yours give me "TypeError: (intermediate value).bind is not a function"

Comment: Try changing from arrow function to lamba (function () {}).

Comment: Im new to react but wouldnt you just use `this.removeProductRow = this.removeProductRow.bind(this)` in the `constructor` to bind `this` to the function?

Comment: why are you binding the invokation of `this.setState()`?

Comment: @Sagivb.g trail and error method,

Comment: OK, and when you remove the `.bind` is it still throwing errors?

Comment: @CodeSpirit yes spirit, that it is, if I removed this and just try this.setState({posRow:null}) I`m still getting not a function error

Comment: @Sagivb.g yes, when I'm trying jut to `this.setState({posRow:null})` I`m still getting the same error

Comment: `bind` only works when referencing a function variable, not when _calling_ a function. However, I highly doubt you'll need to create a new lexical `this` within your `setState` context. You can just call `setState` directly. Try to read up on `setState` from the official React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Answer (score 2):

`setState` should be binded to `React.Component`, when you call `this.setState.bind(this)` you are actually binding it to `removeProductRow`, just remove the `.bind(this)`

Comment: when I`m trying just to: `this.setState({rowPos: null})` I`m getting TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: setState is already binded to the `React.Component`, but he was changing it's default bind value

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I would do different.

First: Fixing the remove method.

```
removeProductRow(index){
  let positionsUpdated = this.state.params.invoice.positions.filter((_, idx) => idx !== index);
  // update just the positions of the state.
  // try to create paramsUdpated yourself.
  this.setState({params: paramsUdpated});
};
```

Second: In render I would not pass callback to props, just the name of the function and use prop itemIndex to get the index of the positions array in ItemRow component.

```
{this.state.params.invoice.positions.map(function(item,index){
  return (<ItemRow key={index} itemIndex={index} removeProductRow={this.removeProductRow}/>)}
```

Working example of my idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sun-tb76r

Comment: if I`m not binding this on map I`m getting 'this is undefined' in this map when I`m passing removeProductRow={this.removeProductRow}

Comment: @ArturJuźwik Created demo for you to better show my solution (click on item to remove it): https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sun-tb76r

Comment: Many thanks, your solution works, no idea why but I will analize it later, can you explain me what do you pass in filter params?

Comment: Filter method takes callback function as first parameter, then in the callback function first parameter is current array item, the second is index of the current array item. Reference to array.filter method is available in this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter